# How to modify custom event listener property of class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my own library, and i have a class which contains few evens and event handlers. I want to overwrite event handler properties of that class.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GUtf7/) is my sample class

```
var MyClass=function(){
    var myFunction=function(){
        $(document).trigger("myEvent")
    }
    var onMyEventCalled=function(){};
    $(document).on("myEvent",onMyEventCalled);
    return{
        myFunction:myFunction,
        onMyEventCalled:onMyEventCalled
    }
}
```

Now I am creating an object of that class and modifying event handler,but it is not working

```
 var obj=new MyClass();
    obj.onMyEventCalled=function(){
       alert("Custom event Changed");
    }
    obj.myFunction();
```

Comment: Since the sample class is small, just add it to your question as well. Keep the link, too, but show the code here.

Comment: Updated the question on your request. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The `onMyEventCalled` function reference that you set as the listener will forever hold that function. If you put there something like (but not exactly, because `this` is not the instance of your object) `function () { return this.onMyEventCalled.apply(this, arguments); }`, it will use the one that you define later. Of course, you have to define a default, too (`this.onMyEventCalled = function () {};`).